# '.class' expected in Java

Tags: java, sorting, compiler-errors

i have an error when i run my code in Java,

MY CODE:

```
interface myFunc{
int func(int n[]);
}
class bubbleSort{
int bubble(int n[]){
    int result[];

    for(int j=0;j<n.length;j++){
        for(int i=j+1;i<n.length;i++){
            if(n[i] < n[j]){
                int t = n[j];
                n[j] = n[i];
                n[i] = t;
                result = t;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}
class test{
public static int lista(myFunc mf, int n){
    return mf.func(n[]);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int intInt[] = {3,2,5,4,1};
    int intOut;

    bubbleSort sort = new bubbleSort();

    intOut = lista(sort::bubble, intInt[]);

    System.out.println(intOut);
}
}
```

MY ERROR:

```
test.java:23: error: '.class' expected
        return mf.func(n[]);
                          ^ test.java:31: error: '.class' expected
        intOut = lista(sort::bubble, intInt[]);
                                             ^ 2 errors error: compilation failed
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem and explain?

Comment: It still not work, can you show me fixed code?

Comment: this same error

Comment: One suggestion I have, is to refresh your knowledge on arrays, including their syntax and how they're used. When you use `int name[]` you've just declared a primitive integer array; note, however, that in Java it is preferable to place the `[]` on the _type_ rather than the variable name: `int[] name`. When using an array as an argument to a method call you should not include the `[]`. Also, the fixes I offered in a previous (now deleted) comment focused on the compilation errors you specifically mentioned, but you apparently have other problems as well—specifically, type mismatch errors.

Comment: At least some of the problems: (1) You call `lista(bubble::sort, intInt[])` which is incorrect syntax, just use `intInt`; (2) You have the same problem with `mf.func(n[])`; (3) The second parameter of `lista` is currently an `int` though I suspect it's supposed to be an `int[]`; (4) The `bubble` method is declared to return an `int` but you try to return an `int[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about what you want, but at least this one is compiles.
Is returning the maximum of the array, or -1 if the array is empty/null.

Not sure if you are looking for this or the sorted array.

As said by Slaw, most of the problems were syntax and mismatch between int[] and int.

```
interface myFunc{

    int func(int n[]);

}

class bubbleSort {

    int bubble(int n[]){
        // int result = 0;

        if(n == null || n.length == 0){
            return -1;
        }

        for(int j=0;j<n.length;j++){
            for(int i=j+1;i<n.length;i++){
                if(n[i] > n[j]){
                    int t = n[j];
                    n[j] = n[i];
                    n[i] = t;
                   // result = t; // You dont need this... i think...
                }
            }

        }

        return n[0];
    }
}

class test {

    public static int lista(myFunc mf, int[] n){
        return mf.func(n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int intInt[] = {4,3,1,20,3,6,10};
        int intOut;

        bubbleSort sort = new bubbleSort();

        intOut = lista(sort::bubble, intInt);

        System.out.println(intOut);
    }
}
```